# laravel eager loading showing incomplete result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've an issue while performing eager loading.

There are two tables

1. Services w/ columns

ser_id | ser_name  | ser_hr

2. Organizations w/columns

   org_id | ser_id | org_name | org_desc

Services and organizations is in 1 to 1 relationship i.e. 1 service is related to only 1 organization.

So in my services model, i wrote a function to show the relation

```
public function organization(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Organization','org_id');
}
```

now in my Services controller,

i tried to build the eloquent query with eager loading

```
$services = Service::with('organization')->orderBy('ser_id','DESC')->get();
```

when i dump the result, half of the associations are missing, i.e when i show the services with organizations, though it should show organization details , it is missing on half of the result.

So i am wondering why the query is fetching the result of organization for some services while some are empty?

Is there any ways to debug how the query is fetching the result?

Result:

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [ser_id] => 6092
                        [ser_date] => 2018-03-18
                        [ser_hr] => 5
                        [ser_min] => 0
                        [std_id] => 362
                        [serty_id] => 4
                        [sers_id] => 3
                        [school_year] => 2016-08-23
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [adv_id] => 109
                        [flag] => 0
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [ser_id] => 6092
                        [ser_date] => 2018-03-18
                        [ser_hr] => 5
                        [ser_min] => 0
                        [std_id] => 362
                        [serty_id] => 4
                        [sers_id] => 3
                        [school_year] => 2016-08-23
                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [adv_id] => 109
                        [flag] => 0
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [organization] => 
                    )
```

[image]

As you can see, i should get organization result for ser_id 6092 , but is showing blank in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your organization table has foreign key `ser_id` from services table, so you should have define relationship in organization model not in services model.

In Organization Model,

```
public function service(){
return $this->hasOne('App\Service','ser_id');
}
```

In your controller

```
$data = Organization::with('service')->orderBy('org_id','DESC')->get();
```

and then you cam access service like this

`$data->service`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship is not quite right.

The second parameter to the hasOne() method is the foreign key. That is, the field on the organizations table that connects the two tables. In this case, that field is `ser_id`, not `org_id`.

Change the second parameter and you should be good to go:

```
public function organization()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Organization', 'ser_id');
}
```